# Add nvm to zsh path

Tags: nodejs

I'm only able to access nvm using bash, I'm trying to add it to my zshrc but unable to find it's install location.

I tried,

```
$ which nvm
```

but that does nothing.

Comment: In `bash`, what does `type -a nvm` say?

Comment: in bash I get `nvm is a function
nvm () 
{ ... }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The README for nvm [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) has some important hints for you.  When installing manually, the doc suggests that you can add the following to your .zshrc file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

I suspect you are missing the first line.  What does `echo $NVM_DIR` show you?

But even better, if you are using a plugin manager, such as [Oh My Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) (and you should be), you can simply install the [zsh-nvm](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm) plugin by adding "nvm" to your list of plugins.

Comment: For zsh, I have nvm listed as `plugins=(colorize git history nvm ...)`. I still get 
`➜  ~ nvm ls`
`zsh: command not found: nvm`

Comment: You didn't quite answer my question.  Can you provide the output of `echo $NVM_DIR` please?

Comment: `/Users/michaelstelly/.nvm`. I think I have it working, though. So it's a non-issue for me now.